# Drupal 8 OpenID Connect not working, returns "Unrecognized username or password"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8, openid-connect

I installed the [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) module on Drupal 8 and configured it. I am able to connect the account with my current admin login for the Drupal 8 website. It shows that the account is connected. But when I try to login to the website using the Google credentials (configured) I still get the error:

> Unrecognized username or password.

Is there something else that I need to activate to enable logging in using Google Credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner and didn't know that I actually had to get the block visible from the structure menu. Got it active on the front page and then saw a button to sign-in with google and that worked seamlessly.